# Media Player for Ubuntu

Tags: sound

Is there a media player for Ubuntu which will reliably play a music CD from start to finish? I have tried for the last 3 months to get Rhythmbox to run without success. It freezes dafter the first song or two.

Comment: Does the problem apply to a particular CD, or every CD thou'st tried?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you play the CD in `totem` (which is actually titled `Videos` in the apps list)? Rhythmbox should play fine, if it doesn't, there's likely a bug, or a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

To properly play disc media on Ubuntu, you will need to install and setup `libdvdcss`. Instructions and more information can be found on the Ubuntu Help website.

### Banshee Media Player

Banshee used to be the default music player in Ubuntu, before Rhythmbox, and plays a wide range of media formats (including CDs and DVDs). It is available for all supported Ubuntu versions in the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee/).

### VLC Media Player

Available on all three major operating system platforms, VLC Media Player is a popular media player that can, like Banshee, play a variety of media formats. It was created by the VideoLAN team, and makes use of `libdvdcss`. It is available for all supported Ubuntu versions in the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe I have libdvdcss installed. Just tried Banshee again and it froze part way through the first song. Have tried VLC which, for me, has the same problem. Incidentally I am having the same problem with bot of my Ubuntu computers. One is Intel based the other is AMD based.

Comment: Maybe you could try checking if your CD/DVD drive is okay? Or your compact media disc itself?